# How to use Readlink

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, intercept, readlink

How do I use Readlink for fetching the values.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> **Don't do it**

At least not in the way you're proposing.

You specified a solution here without specifying what you really want to do [and why?].  That is, what are your needs/requirements?  Assuming you get it, what do you want to do with the filename?  You posted a bare fragment of your userspace application but didn't post any of your kernel code.

As a long time kernel programmer, I can tell you that this won't work, can't work, and is a *terrible* hack. There is a vast difference in methods to use inside the kernel vs. userspace.

> `/proc` is strictly for userspace applications to snoop on kernel data.  The `/proc` filesystem drivers *assume* userspace, so they always do `copy_to_user`. Data will be written to user address space, and *not* kernel address space, so this will *never* work from within the kernel.

Even if you *could* use `/proc` from within the kernel, it is a genuinely awful way to do it.

You *can* get the equivalent data, but it's a bit more complicated than that.  If you're intercepting the `read` syscall *inside* the kernel, you [already] have access to the `current` task struct and the `fd` number used in the call.  From this, you can locate the struct for the given open file, and get whatever you want, directly, without involving `/proc` at all.  Use this as a starting point.

Note that doing this will necessitate that you read kernel documentation, sources for filesystem drivers, syscalls, etc.  How to lock data structures and lists with the various locking methods (e.g. RCU, rw locks, spinlocks).  Also, per-cpu variables.  kernel thread preemptions. How to *properly* traverse the necessary filesystem related lists and structs to get the information you want.  All this, without causing lockups, panics, segfaults, deadlocks, UB based on stale or inconsistent/dynamically changing data.

You'll need to study all this to become familiar with the way the kernel does things internally, and *understand* it, *before* you try doing something like this.  If you had, you would have read the source code for the `/proc` drivers and already known why things were failing.

As a suggestion, forget anything that you've learned about how a userspace application does things.  It won't apply here.  Internally, the kernel is organized in a completely different way than what you've been used to.

You have no need to use `readlink` inside the kernel in this instance.  That's the way a userspace application would *have* to do it, but in the kernel it's like driving 100 miles out of your way to get data you already have nearby, and, as I mentioned previously, won't even work.